# No low beams but do have high beams

Tags: electrical, toyota, headlight, tundra

I have a 2008 Toyota tundra that I replaced 1 headlight on thinking it was bad but then replaced it a second time and it worked fine for 1 day and the all of a sudden now I do not have any low beams on either side. I have high beams. I was told that maybe a fuse or a relay.

What are the chances that it is just a fuse?

Could it be anything else?

Comment: It is common to have a seperate fuse or relay for the low beams and high beams.  Have you had a chance to check the fuses yet?  That's the first step followed by the relays.

Comment: No I haven't had a chance yet but I will definitely do that thanks for the info I will let you know

Comment: Yes, post all the details, and we'll certainly help you figure this out!

Answer (score 3):

While your're checking fuses, don't overlook the connector(s) on the headlights themselves.  Sometimes they fail over time and other times due to people putting higher wattage bulbs than the connectors can handle.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern headlight bulbs have two filaments in the same glass enclosure: one for low beams, one for high beams. I imagine that you use low beams most of the time, so the corresponding filament burned out sooner.

If you have this problem only with one headlight, I believe this is the reason. If you have this issue with both, I'd start with the fuses and relays.